# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB in UNOIN

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I Have this query that is a UNION of 2 queries, but even I take the same columns in both queries, when I execute it I got an error

```
   SELECT  username,
                sid,
                serial# serial,
                osuser,
                seconds_in_wait,
                sql_address,
                sql_hash_value,
                sql_fulltext
        FROM V$SESSION se
        JOIN v$sql sq ON sq.ADDRESS = se.SQL_ADDRESS
        AND sq.HASH_VALUE = se.SQL_HASH_VALUE
        WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
            AND username <> 'SYSTEM' AND username <> 'SYS'
            AND osuser <> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
            AND osuser <> 'SYSTEM'
            AND seconds_in_wait >= 500

 UNION 
 SELECT  username,
                sid,
                serial# serial,
                osuser,
                seconds_in_wait,
                sql_address,
                sql_hash_value,
                sql_fulltext
from V$SESSION se 
    join v$sql sq on sq.ADDRESS = se.SQL_ADDRESS and sq.HASH_VALUE = se.SQL_HASH_VALUE
where blocking_session is not NULL 
AND seconds_in_wait >= 500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support `UNION` of columns of type CLOB (`sql_fulltext` in your case) are involved.

If `UNION ALL` (instead of `UNION`) works for your query as well, you can use that.

**Update**

You might need to modify your query slightly to avoid duplicates with `UNION ALL` (see last boolean expression in first WHERE clause):

```
SELECT username,
        sid,
        serial# serial,
        osuser,
        seconds_in_wait,
        sql_address,
        sql_hash_value,
        sql_fulltext
    FROM V$SESSION se
    JOIN v$sql sq ON sq.ADDRESS = se.SQL_ADDRESS
        AND sq.HASH_VALUE = se.SQL_HASH_VALUE
    WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
        AND username <> 'SYSTEM' AND username <> 'SYS'
        AND osuser <> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
        AND osuser <> 'SYSTEM'
        AND seconds_in_wait >= 500
        AND blocking_session is NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT username,
        sid,
        serial# serial,
        osuser,
        seconds_in_wait,
        sql_address,
        sql_hash_value,
        sql_fulltext
FROM V$SESSION se 
JOIN v$sql sq ON sq.ADDRESS = se.SQL_ADDRESS
    AND sq.HASH_VALUE = se.SQL_HASH_VALUE
WHERE blocking_session is not NULL 
    AND seconds_in_wait >= 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a UNION to begin with? Your query is equivalent to:

```
   SELECT  username,
                sid,
                serial# serial,
                osuser,
                seconds_in_wait,
                sql_address,
                sql_hash_value,
                sql_fulltext
        FROM V$SESSION se
        JOIN v$sql sq ON sq.ADDRESS = se.SQL_ADDRESS
        AND sq.HASH_VALUE = se.SQL_HASH_VALUE
        WHERE seconds_in_wait >= 500
          AND (     status   =      'ACTIVE'
                AND username not in ('SYSTEM', 'SYS')
                AND osuser   not in ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM')
                OR
                blocking_session is not null
              )
;
```

Then: if in a different problem you couldn't avoid `UNION` (rather than `UNION ALL`), the correct way to do it is to leave out the `CLOB` column at first; select all the other columns, perform the joins and the `UNION` (note that `JOIN` is distributive with respect to `UNION`, so it may be better to do the `UNION` first and only then the `JOIN`), and then `JOIN` back again to retrieve the `CLOB` column.